# Concurrent connections limit in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: http, microsoft-edge, hostname

How many concurrent connections will Microsoft Edge allow per Hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge allows a maximum of six (6) simultaneous TCP connections per hostname. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network